80s-style vampire movie with a delivery boy
I am trying to identify a movie I saw while on a road-trip to Florida when I was very young.
I remember it being 1980s style and American made. The only real scene I remember is that this vampire tries to seduce a Pizza delivery boy (maybe he was something else but memory is foggy). He ended up getting bit by her and running out of the house (I believe he was seduced as well). A storm started as soon as he ran out of the house.
Thanks!

Sounds very much like the premise of My Best Friend is a Vampire from 1987.

In Houston, the teenager Jeremy Capello is a normal middle-class boy, who lives with his beloved parents and has Ralph as his best friend. He has a crush on Darla Blake, but he is shy and does not date her. He works making deliveries for a supermarket and is seduced by his sexy client Nora. While having his first intercourse with her, Jeremy is transformed in a vampire.

Here are some clips from the film:



